# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.afollestad:material-dialogs:2.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

**I, m using Android Studio 3.3, and in my project I hava a problem with com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:2.0.0, when I add com.afollestad.material-dialogs to my Gradle, error was show: Failed to resolve: com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:2.0.0,**

Here is my Gradle: Project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

My Gradle: app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pongodev.recipesapp"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 5
        versionName "3.0.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Main libraries, you always need this libraries in your project. do not remove them.
    implementation'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'

    // Important library to create material design. do not remove this.
    implementation project(':materialDesign')

    // Library to create tabbar
    implementation 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.6'

    // Library to create ripple effect. work together with materialDesign library.
    implementation 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'

    // Library to create rounded, circle, and any shape image.
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.4.0'

    // Library load lazy images.
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    // Library to create simple list.
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    // Library to create complex clickable list.
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

    // Library to create material dialog.
    implementation 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:2.0.0'

    // Library to create animation imageview.
    implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.5'

}
```

My Gradle: materialDesign

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:2.0.0'` to `implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:2.0.0'`
 in your app module's gradle file.

**EDIT:**

Make sure you already have `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` this line in Project level build.gralde file. If it is not present then add this line like

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

   }
}
```

Comment: I have a good internet connection. so, there is no any problem of the internet.

Comment: log file is too long! what should I do?

Comment: Paste by editing your question and this is not what I asked for. I think you're new to the Android Studio environment, so just take a snap of the error which is showing on Android Studio.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I'm new to the Android environment. I'm sending you the snap of the error. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Snap of Error:   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BrbiRdXpJtC-GaGiM-G3OVlEwHeyq_GP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: still having a problem. ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.afollestad:material-dialogs:core

Comment: Try `File->Invalidate cache and Restart Android Studio`

Comment: i have did it two times! still have a problem!

Comment: Are you able to Sync without any error when you remove this library?